# Expandable contact information

Tags: macros, expansion

## Introduction

I am sorry for the long MWE, but I was not able to make it shorter and still illustrate my problem. Again I am working on streamlining the creation of exams for my university. In the example below the user can add more lectures using

```
\defineInfo{jane}{
  name=Jane Doe, 
  phone=75123123,
}
```

(Where I got help creating the syntax in [Contact list as dictionary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504115/contact-list-as-dictionary/504118?noredirect=1#comment1273401_504118)) Add information about the exam using

```
\FrontpageUiTsetup{
  contact = jane,
}
```

(Now with the help from [Labeled input parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503983/labeled-input-parameters/504129#504129)) Where the last command of course has a lot more parameters, irrelevant to my question. Now, I want to combine these two answers, so I can refer to a lecturer using an ID, and then print the relevant parts in `\FrontpageUiT`.

I first tried writing

```
\ifx\@contact\@empty\else
  \contactname & \contactInfo{\@contact}{name}\\%
\fi
```

However, it seems the `\contactInfo` command expands before `\@contact` so it outputs nothing. After a bit of googling I was able to use the following to expand `\@contact` first

```
\newcommand{\expandMacro}[1]{
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand#1%
  }\x
}
```

## Problem

So here comes my problem:

- *I want the default value of @phone and @mobile to be defined by respectively the lines `\contactInfo{\@contact}{mobile}` and `\contactInfo{\@contact}{phone}`*

The problem comes when I want the line

```
\contactmobile & \@mobile
```

To be blank when no mobile number is given. Example:

```
    mobile        .tl_set:N  = \@mobile,
    mobile        .initial:n = {\expandMacro{\contactInfo{\@contact}{mobile}}},
    phone         .tl_set:N  = \@phone,
    phone         .initial:n = {\expandMacro{\contactInfo{\@contact}{phone}}},
.
.
.
  \ifx\@contact\@empty\else
    \contactname & \expandMacro{\contactInfo{\@contact}{name}}\\%
  \fi

  \ifx\@mobile\@empty\else
    \contactmobile & \@mobile\\%
  \fi

  \ifx\@phone\@empty\else
    \contactphone & \@phone\\%
.
.
.

\defineInfo{jane}{
  name=Jane Doe, 
  phone=75123123,
}

\FrontpageUiTsetup{
  contact = jane,
}

\begin{document}
\FrontpageUiT
\end{document}
```

As Jane has no mobile number, I would expect the output to be

```
Contact    Jane Doe
Phone      75 12 31 23
```

Instead I am faced with

```
Contact    Jane Doe
Mobile
Phone      75 12 31 23
```

The problem is that the code can not expand `\contactInfo{\@contact}{mobile}` fast enough to realize that it is empty. After a bit more googling I found

```
\newcommand{\IfNoText}[3]{%
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd0=0pt %
    {#2}% if #1 is empty
  \else%
    \ifdim0pt=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
      {#2}% if #1 is empty
    \else
      {#3}% if #1 is not empty
    \fi
  \fi%
}
```

That can detect if the output is blank. However, it does not support ampersand (&), so I can not use it in my table. E.G

```
\IfNoText{\@mobile}{}{Mobile & \@mobile \\}
```

throws me an error. I tried also to use `\IfNoText` earlier in my document to define toggles that expand to true or false based on the contents of `\@mobile`. However, these did not expand fast enough either.

- Is there a way to check that `\@mobile` and `@phone` is empty faster, when they are given in the terms of `\contactInfo`?

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand{\IfNoText}[3]{%
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd0=0pt %
    {#2}% if #1 is empty
  \else%
    \ifdim0pt=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
      {#2}% if #1 is empty
    \else
      {#3}% if #1 is not empty
    \fi
  \fi%
}

\newcommand{\expandMacro}[1]{
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand#1%
  }\x
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineInfo}{mm}
 {
  \prop_new:c { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\contactInfo}{mm}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #2 }
   {
    {phone}  { \nebu_phone:e { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } } }
    {mobile} { \nebu_phone:e { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } } }
   }
   { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } }
 }

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_contact_prop:n
 {
  g_nebu_contact_\str_lowercase:n { #1 }_prop
 }

%%% formatting phone numbers
\NewDocumentCommand{\phone}{m}
 {
  \nebu_phone:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__nebu_phone_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nebu_phone:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { #1 }
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { ~ }
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:N \l__nebu_phone_tl = 8 }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_eight:V \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \nebu_phone:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
   {
    {4}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {8}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {9}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
   }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n { V }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2#3\hspace{1ex}#4#5\hspace{1ex}#6#7#8 }
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2\hspace{0.6666ex}#3#4\hspace{0.6666ex}#5#6\hspace{0.6666ex}#7#8 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504129/8306
%
% This creates the backbone for the frontpage. One can add new keys here
\makeatletter
  % Provide commands.
  \ExplSyntaxOn
    % Provide keys.
    \keys_define:nn { babylonia }
      {
        contact       .tl_set:N  = \@contact,
        mobile        .tl_set:N  = \@mobile,
        mobile        .initial:n = {\expandMacro{\contactInfo{\@contact}{mobile}}},
        phone         .tl_set:N  = \@phone,
        phone         .initial:n = {\expandMacro{\contactInfo{\@contact}{phone}}},
      }
    % Provide key setting command.
    \NewDocumentCommand\FrontpageUiTsetup{ m }{
      \keys_set:nn { babylonia } { #1 }
    }
  \ExplSyntaxOff
  % Provide names.
  \newcommand*\contactname{Contact}
  \newcommand*\contactmobile{Mobile}
  \newcommand*\contactphone{Phone}
  % The typesetting command.
  \newcommand\FrontpageUiT{%

    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{\dimexpr 0.8\textwidth - 4\tabcolsep}}

      \ifx\@contact\@empty\else
        \contactname & \expandMacro{\contactInfo{\@contact}{name}}\\%
      \fi

      \ifx\@mobile\@empty\else
        \contactmobile & \@mobile\\%
      \fi

      \ifx\@phone\@empty\else
        \contactphone & \@phone\\%
      \fi

    \end{tabular}%
  }
\makeatother

% ==============================================================================
%   User interface below here
% ==============================================================================

% This adds contacts to be used in the UiT frontpage
% Example:
%
% \defineInfo{joe}{
%   name=Joe Doe, mobile=32132132, phone=93123123,
% }

\defineInfo{jane}{
  name=Jane Doe, 
  phone=75123123,
}

\FrontpageUiTsetup{
  contact = jane,
}

\begin{document}

\FrontpageUiT

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add two commands, one for testing the presence of a property, the other for typesetting the info.

```latex
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\contactTestTF}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = contact, #2 = property to test, #3 = code for true, #4 = code for false
  \prop_if_in:cnTF { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\FrontpageUiTsetup}{m}
 {
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}
  \contactname & \contactInfo{#1}{name} \\
  \contactTestTF{#1}{mobile}{\mobilename & \contactInfo{#1}{mobile} \\}{}
  \contactTestTF{#1}{phone}{\phonename & \contactInfo{#1}{phone} \\}{}
  \end{tabular}
 }
```

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineInfo}{mm}
 {
  \prop_new:c { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\contactInfo}{mm}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #2 }
   {
    {phone}  { \nebu_phone:e { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } } }
    {mobile} { \nebu_phone:e { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } } }
   }
   { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\contactTestTF}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = contact, #2 = property to test, #3 = code for true, #4 = code for false
  \prop_if_in:cnTF { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\FrontpageUiTsetup}{m}
 {
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}
  \contactname & \contactInfo{#1}{name} \\
  \contactTestTF{#1}{mobile}{\mobilename & \contactInfo{#1}{mobile} \\}{}
  \contactTestTF{#1}{phone}{\phonename & \contactInfo{#1}{phone} \\}{}
  \end{tabular}
 }

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_contact_prop:n
 {
  g_nebu_contact_\str_lowercase:n { #1 }_prop
 }

%%% formatting phone numbers
\NewDocumentCommand{\phone}{m}
 {
  \nebu_phone:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__nebu_phone_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nebu_phone:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { #1 }
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { ~ }
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:N \l__nebu_phone_tl = 8 }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_eight:V \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \nebu_phone:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
   {
    {4}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {8}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {9}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
   }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n { V }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2#3\nobreakspace#4#5\nobreakspace#6#7#8 }
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2\nobreakspace#3#4\nobreakspace#5#6\nobreakspace#7#8 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\contactname}{Contact}
\newcommand{\mobilename}{Mobile}
\newcommand{\phonename}{Phone}

\defineInfo{jane}{
  name=Jane Doe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=45123123,
}
\defineInfo{joe}{
  name=Joe Doe,
  %mobile=32132132,
  phone=93123123,
}
\defineInfo{richard}{
  name=Richard Roe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=83123123,
}

\begin{document}

\contactInfo{Jane}{name} has \contactInfo{jane}{mobile} mobile phone.

\contactInfo{riCHard}{phone} is \contactInfo{Richard}{name}'s phone.

\bigskip

\FrontpageUiTsetup{jane}

\bigskip

\FrontpageUiTsetup{joe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work great, but I can not make it work for my example. I would rather not redefine `\FrontpageUiTsetup` as this probably will take in 10-15 named commands, in addition to the `lecturer ID`.  It would look something like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503983/labeled-input-parameters/504129#504129. I dont understand why `\contactTestTF{\@contact}{mobile}` does not work =/ I am working towards `\FrontpageUiT` to create something like https://i.imgur.com/VLQ1sd5.png.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Why mixing legacy programming with `expl3`?

Comment: Without trying to start a long discussion: which part is legacy programming? I am simply trying to create a setup file (like `hypersetup`) to create a table. One of the entries in this setup is an `id` that identifies an lecturer. If this `id` is present, then I want to be able to choose whether or not to print the name, phone and mobile associated with that `id`. 
If you have a "non legacy" way of achieving what I am trying to do, I am all ears =)